# Standard Plot size in Python-matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, axis, patch, rectangles

I am generating multiple plots using matplotlib.patches.rect depending on the requirements. Some cases 2 rectangles are plotted sometimes 4 rectangles. But the visualisation size differs depending on the numbers of such rectangles although the dimensions of rectangles remains the same. Here in my case every rectangle has fixed shape (1200X230).

Below is the entire working code:

```
sampledata = {'Layer':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'Type':[1,1,2,2,2,2]} 
ip0 = pd.DataFrame(sampledata, columns=['Layer','Type'])
for i in range(ip0['Type'].nunique()):
  fig = plt.figure() 
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  ip = ip0[ip0['Type']== i+1]
  b = i+1
  ax.grid(linestyle='--',linewidth = '0.3', color = 'black')
  for i in range(ip['Layer'].nunique()):
    y_pos = (i*300)
    r = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle(xy=(0, y_pos), width=1201,height=233, 
        facecolor = None, edgecolor = 'red', linewidth=1.2, fill = False)
    ax.text(-230, y_pos+175, 'Layer-{}'.format(i), 
    color='g',rotation='vertical', fontsize= (36/ip['Layer'].nunique()))
    ax.add_patch(r)

plt.xlim([0, 1500]) 
plt.ylim([0, (ip['Layer'].nunique()*300)]) 
plt.savefig(f'image_bin_{b}.jpeg',bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 
1600,transparent=True)
```

I have attached pictures of 2 cases one where there 2 rectangles and one 4. Please help me making them look similar since the actual dimensions are equal.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a runnable code so we can help you.

Comment: @Liris I have updated with the code. Could you please check now.

Comment: If you want your rectangles to be similar in both figures, you have to work with fixed limits in both axes. Or your `ylim` changes between both.

Comment: @Liris Understood, but then unnecessarily the size is reducing even if the rectangles are of less numbers. Can we make something that the size for 4 rectangles remains same as of that 2 rectangles case?

Comment: Same answer, as soon as you fix the boundaries of the axis, the rectangle size and the figure size, they'll print with the same size on your screen.

Comment: But when i restrict with a lesser limit, lets say i am restricting at 600, then in case of 4 rectangles, only 2 rectangles are getting plotted while other 2 are not.

Comment: You have to set the higher limit the max value, instead of restricting it. In your example, set it to 1200.

Comment: So, then in case of 2 rectangles, the size is getting reduced which is not desirable..Have to trade off between something i guess.